# How can i get StackPanel's children StackPanel from code?

Tags: wpf

Here is my `StackPanel` "group", and i want my children `stackPanel` visibility state change to Visible, but in codebehind i didn't see the children stackpanel's name.

This is only pseudo:

```
<StackPanel X.Name="MainStack">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
             something...              
       </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel x:name="Stack" Grid.Column="1" Visibility=Collapsed>
             something...              
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
             something...              
       </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I'am trying from code to change visibility to Visible but I cant.

```
MainStack.Children(Stack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
```

Without `MainStack.Children`, the program didn't see the children Stack name.

Comment: If you can access `MainStack` you should also be able to access `Stack` in the same way as it's same name scope. Also I assume that in both cases you use `x:Name="..."` and not `X.Name` or `x:name`

Comment: Why don't you bind the visibility to a model? :) Single boolean value switch and it's visible.

Comment: dkozy Its just pseudo! I'am writting x:Name everywere :) Thanks for help to all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer updated to cover recursive child lookup.

You can do something like --

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)     where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
        {
            yield return (T)child;
        }

        foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
        {
            yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
foreach (var p in FindVisualChildren<StackPanel>(MainStack))
{
    p.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: It's not me who down voted but direct child of main `StackPanel` is a `Grid`. Your code will always return empty list in this case

Comment: me too :( i have an account, and that is blocked because of vote downs :(
you are awesome, but i Cant vote right now